# ROS2 generating 'core' file on error, how to disable?

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running a simple talker/listener demo, using a Docker image based on ros:galactic-ros-core  w/ros-galactic-desktop installed. I'm getting an error about half the time when I run the demo, but my question is not about the error, but about the core dump. When I get the error, a large file "core" is created in the current directory which I really don't want. Is this standard behavior? Is there any supported method to stop this from happening by default, either within ROS2 or linux?

Following a cryptic comment from https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ros-programming-building/9781788627436/fa252378-8d64-4c42-ad20-e8a5374549a5.xhtml "... there is already a core directory to prevent core dumps" I can prevent the 'core' file from being created by creating an empty 'core' directory in the current working directory, but this is a workaround.

Not necessarily relevant, but here's the script creating the error:

```
# start talker and listener in background
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker &
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener &
sleep 10
kill %+
kill %-
```

and the error is "Failed to create log directory: /root/.ros/log"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388704/ros2-generating-%27core%27-file-on-error,-how-to-disable?/) by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2021-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-15**:
off-topic for your question, but

> I'm running a simple talker/listener demo [..] I'm getting an error about half the time when I run the demo

is this an unaltered demo package part of the default ROS 2 set?

If it is, I would encourage you to report the crashes you're seeing, as they should not happen.

**Comment by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on 2021-10-15**:
This can be duplicated, though intermittently,  with the standard components from package demo_nodes_cpp and osrf:/ros:galactic-desktop. Where would I file the bug? The demo files it is based on a pretty simple, the issue is probably in roscpp.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-16**:
The issue tracker for the `demos` packages is [ros2/demos/issues](https://github.com/ros2/demos/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Core dumps are not specific to ROS (1 or 2), managed by it or created by any of the client libraries, but a feature of your OS. See #q260977 for a previous Q&A about them.

They're actually a very useful thing to have after a crash, as they allow a developer to debug a process *post-mortem* (ie: after it has already crashed and been terminated by the OS).

As to disabling their generation, you could take a look at the [Arch documentation on Core dump](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Core_dump#Disabling_automatic_core_dumps)s.

The Docker image you mention (`ros:galactic-ros-core`) is based on Ubuntu Focal. Canonical doesn't appear to have any documentation specifically about the configuration of core dumps (that I can find). The [ulimit section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Core_dump#Using_ulimit) in the Arch documentation should work however, as it's for Bash in general. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232) also has some information.

---

Edit: I'm hesitant to duplicate information that's so easily found already, but to make this answer more self-contained:

To disable core dumps in the current Bash session: `ulimit -c 0`.

Or edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and set `soft core` for `*` (ie: all users) to `0` (see again the Arch documentation linked earlier).

And just to reiterate: this is OS-level configuration. Not ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on 2021-10-15**:
I tried the fix in /etc/security/limits.conf earlier and it did not prevent the core file from appearing. But ulimit -c 0 seems to work when I do it in the current session. Thanks!